# Keep vertical UIStackView at the minimum width when the alignment is center

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, uistackview

If I create a `UIStackView` with `vertical` axis and `center` alignment, how do I keep its `width` at the minimum possible value, meaning the widest subview?

I can't create a constraint between it and one of the subviews because I don't know which one will be the widest.

This usually happens when I create a leading `greater than or equal` constraint to the view controller's view with constant 10, and a center horizontally constraint.

In this case, the stack view will have the width equal to the view controller's width - 20, while the subviews will retain their width (e.g. from their intrinsic content sizes if they're labels).

Here is an example:

```
A--------------+
| B----------+ |
| |   C--+   | |
| |   +--+   | |
| | D------+ | |
| | |      | | |
| | +------+ | |
| +----------+ |
+--------------+
```

where `A` is the view controller's view, `B` is the stack view and `C` and `D` are two labels.

So it leaves a gap between the left margins of `B` and `D`.

I would instead expect it to look like this:

```
A--------------+
|   B------+   |
|   | C--+ |   |
|   | +--+ |   |
|   D------+   |
|   |      |   |
|   +------+   |
|   +------+   |
+--------------+
```

where the `B`'s width is equal to `D`'s width, because the leading constraint is `greater than or equal`, and **not** strictly `equal`.

Comment: that is the default behavior.. what else are you doing?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, I edited my question with an example and more info.

Comment: As @MilanNosáľ said, stack views will do this by default (they know how to size themselves based on their contents). If yours is not doing that, you need to post your code.